# How to return data from object function without accessing function object with dot

Tags: python, oop

I have the following:

```py
class JsonSerializable(object):
    def to_json(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class InlineKeyboardMarkup(JsonSerializable):
    def __init__(self, inline_keyboard):
        self.inline_keyboard = inline_keyboard

    def to_json(self):
        obj = {'inline_keyboard': self.inline_keyboard}
        return json.dumps(obj)
```

I need the InlineKeyboardMarkup return without accessing .to_json()
like this:

```py
>>> InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[])
... '{"inline_keyboard":[]}'
```

Comment: Define a `__repr__()` method that calls `to_json()`?  This could be done in the base class, rather than repeating it for each subclass.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to display it in the `repl` loop, you can just override `__repr__`, which is called under the hood by `print`:

```
class InlineKeyboardMarkup(JsonSerializable):
    def __init__(self, inline_keyboard):
        self.inline_keyboard = inline_keyboard

    def to_json(self):
        obj = {'inline_keyboard': self.inline_keyboard}
        return json.dumps(obj)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.to_json())
```

Comment: through a failed  test (AssertionError)
```python
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[])
assert markup == {"inline_keyboard": []}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **repr** :

```py
import json


class JsonSerializable(object):
    def to_json(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class InlineKeyboardMarkup(JsonSerializable):
    def __init__(self, inline_keyboard):
        self.inline_keyboard = inline_keyboard

    def to_json(self):
        obj = {'inline_keyboard': self.inline_keyboard}
        return json.dumps(obj)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.to_json())


def test_inline_keyboard_markup():
    dic = r'{"inline_keyboard": [[{}, {}], [{}]]}'
    obj = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[{}, {}], [{}]])
    assert obj == dic
```

pytest-3 object.py -vvv

```
ERROR collecting objects.py
objects.py:27: in <module>
    test_inline_keyboard_markup()
objects.py:24: in test_inline_keyboard_markup
    assert obj == dic
E   assert '{"inline_keyboard": [[{}, {}], [{}]]}' == '{"inline_keyboard": [[{}, {}], [{}]]}'

Interrupted: 1 errors during collection 
1 error in 0.58 seconds
```